# Is assigning promises to variables and returning in chains different than just returning the promise call?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is there any difference in the way these two chains are handled or are they handled in the same way? Is there any benefit to using one over the other?

I've tried both calls and they both return the same result (32) -- and my assumption is that they process in the same manner but I have a friend who is telling me they work differently.

```
const getNewDataPromise = num => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    typeof num === 'number' ? resolve(num * 2) : 
        reject(`${num} is not a number -- input must be a numeric value.`);
});

getNewDataPromise(2).then( data => {
    const nowEight = getNewDataPromise(data);
    return nowEight;
}).then( data => {
    const nowSixteen = getNewDataPromise(data);
    return nowSixteen;
}).then( data => {
    const nowThirtyTwo = getNewDataPromise(data);
    return nowThirtyTwo
}).then( data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
});

getNewDataPromise(2).then( data => {
    return getNewDataPromise(data);
}).then( data => {
    return getNewDataPromise(data);
}).then( data => {
    return getNewDataPromise(data);
}).then( data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch( err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything at all before they're being returned, there's no difference. An extra variable name in a scope doesn't do anything by itself

Comment: No difference between the two.  Same reason there's no difference between `return 2` and `var x = 2; return x;`.  No difference.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to make sure -- that was my argument but he was adamant that I was wrong in this case and that one was (the second example) was called in serial, whereas the first example would be called in parallel which is not my understanding.

Comment: Your Javascript runs single threaded so your actual Javascript instructions never run in parallel.  Asynchronous operations can be in-flight in parallel, but that's difference that two lines of JS running in parallel.  And, regardless breaking one line of code into two lines doesn't change any of this.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would.

Comment: Of course this is subjective but I think one benefit is readability. One way to make it even more readable: `.then(getNewDataPromise).then(getNewDataPromise)` and so on.

Comment: also remember that arrow functions are returning, so your second block still looks too verbose: `.then(data => getNewDataPromise(data))` makes that code even nicer. (and see the comment above this one if `this` preservation is not required, in which case you don't even need an arrow function)

Comment: This is what I ended up with: `getNewDataPromise(2).then( data =>  getNewDataPromise(data)).then( data => getNewDataPromise(data)).then( data => getNewDataPromise(data)).then( data => { console.log(data); }).catch( err => { console.log(err); });` with newlines of course

Thanks @robbannn and @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference at all between your two versions in terms of outcome.  The first one just creates an intermediate local variable which doesn't affect the outcome or parallelism or anything like your friend has asserted.

Your second one is more concise and just as clear and would be my preference between your two.

---

Another option would be to use `async/await` which is particularly useful for sequences of asynchronous operations:

```
async function run() {
    try {
        let data = await getNewDataPromise(2);
        data = await getNewDataPromise(data);
        data = await getNewDataPromise(data);
        data = await getNewDataPromise(data);
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Or, if you were really just calling the same function over and over, you could use a loop too which would be a bit less repetitive (more DRY):

```
async function run() {
    try {
        let data = 2;
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            data = await getNewDataPromise(data);
        }
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```